# Add column based on header cell; then remove header cell

Tags: r, dataframe

I have interesting data that is not uniform. A group of items are listed under the category name, but it is all in the same column. I need to add a column with the row corresponding to the item's category that it belongs to (then remove the category heading). The only way to distinguish a new category is determining whether the value under the year is empty.... My dputs should explain my issue more clearly.

Before:

```
structure(list(X = structure(c(13L, 1L, 19L, 16L, 5L, 17L, 11L, 
8L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 18L, 15L, 21L, 12L, 14L, 9L, 3L, 20L, 7L
), .Label = c("-Burgers", "-Cameras", "-Shirts", "+Laptops", 
"+Salads", "+TVs", "Caps", "Cell", "Clothes:", "Desktops", "Electronics", 
"Flowers", "Food", "Garden Nomes", "Grills", "Hotdogs", "Nachoes", 
"Outdoors:", "Pizza", "Shorts", "Swimming Gear"), class = "factor"), 
X2000 = c(NA, 104L, 159L, 184L, 189L, 182L, NA, 49L, 28L, 
46L, 34L, 43L, NA, 129L, 190L, 189L, 119L, NA, 45L, 80L, 
80L), X2001 = c(NA, 147L, 192L, 164L, 174L, 196L, NA, 40L, 
34L, 43L, 35L, 22L, NA, 114L, 130L, 120L, 145L, NA, 56L, 
35L, 54L), X2002 = c(NA, 163L, 172L, 138L, 146L, 190L, NA, 
38L, 40L, 21L, 22L, 33L, NA, 186L, 172L, 139L, 119L, NA, 
88L, 78L, 91L), X2003 = c(NA, 125L, 152L, 182L, 148L, 125L, 
NA, 36L, 44L, 34L, 27L, 50L, NA, 119L, 115L, 188L, 166L, 
NA, 91L, 77L, 77L), X2004 = c(NA, 116L, 111L, 120L, 153L, 
199L, NA, 49L, 48L, 43L, 37L, 32L, NA, 159L, 116L, 143L, 
153L, NA, 18L, 53L, 51L)), .Names = c("X", "X2000", "X2001", 
"X2002", "X2003", "X2004"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

After:

```
structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 15L, 13L, 5L, 14L, 8L, 2L, 
9L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 17L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 16L, 7L), .Label = c("-Burgers", 
"-Cameras", "-Shirts", "+Laptops", "+Salads", "+TVs", "Caps", 
"Cell", "Desktops", "Flowers", "Garden Nomes", "Grills", "Hotdogs", 
"Nachoes", "Pizza", "Shorts", "Swimming Gear"), class = "factor"), 
X.1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Clothes:", "Electronics", 
"Food", "Outdoors:"), class = "factor"), X2000 = c(104L, 
159L, 184L, 189L, 182L, 49L, 28L, 46L, 34L, 43L, 129L, 190L, 
189L, 119L, 45L, 80L, 80L), X2001 = c(147L, 192L, 164L, 174L, 
196L, 40L, 34L, 43L, 35L, 22L, 114L, 130L, 120L, 145L, 56L, 
35L, 54L), X2002 = c(163L, 172L, 138L, 146L, 190L, 38L, 40L, 
21L, 22L, 33L, 186L, 172L, 139L, 119L, 88L, 78L, 91L), X2003 = c(125L, 
152L, 182L, 148L, 125L, 36L, 44L, 34L, 27L, 50L, 119L, 115L, 
188L, 166L, 91L, 77L, 77L), X2004 = c(116L, 111L, 120L, 153L, 
199L, 49L, 48L, 43L, 37L, 32L, 159L, 116L, 143L, 153L, 18L, 
53L, 51L)), .Names = c("X", "X.1", "X2000", "X2001", "X2002", 
"X2003", "X2004"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L
))
```

The items are arbitrarily have + or - signs...I need that to remain the same. Also, some category headers have : while others do not.

Comment: I'm guessing "Nomes" vs "nomes" is a typo...?

Comment: @Frank Thanks for notifying that.  I was wondering why I am not getting the identical output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create an index based on the 'NA' values in columns other than the 1st ('indx').  We `split` the dataset using the 'indx', remove the first row i.e. `NA` values from columns 2nd to the last, `cbind` with the 1st row, 1st column value, rearrange the columns and `rbind`.

```
indx <- cumsum(!rowSums(!is.na(df1[-1])))
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df1, indx), function(x) 
          cbind(x, X.1= x[1,1])[-1,c(1,7,2:6)]))
row.names(res) <- NULL 
all.equal(res, out, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

where 'out' is the `dput` output of the expected result

#### Update

If the columns have `''` instead of `NA`,

```
indx <- cumsum(!rowSums(df1[-1]!=''))
```

and do the rest as above.  Having said that, when we have `''` in a numeric column, the class will be either `factor` or `character` based on whether you specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or `=TRUE` in the `read.table/read.csv`.  So, keeping the `''` as such will get the output also a `factor/character` class.  I would convert the columns to their correct class first which will also coerce the `''` to `NA`, i.e.

```
 df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

The `as.character` is only needed if the columns are `factor` class.

Once, we have done the conversion, the first approach should work fine as well.

Comment: Simpler splitting rule: `cumsum(is.na(df1[[2]]))`

Comment: @Frank I thought about it, but then if the OP considers that all the values in a row should be `NA` as a condition.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the index to make it according to a row being empty instead of NA. So the entire row value would just be blank.  ""

Comment: @Hsaj  You may have to replace `is.na` with `df1[-1]==''`  I have to go now.  Will check it later

Comment: @akrun Thanks for everything so far. No urgency--will continue tomorrow.